# Entity framework is trying to use a table that doesn't exist in the SQL for a navigation property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In my C# application (an ASP.NET MVC5 website) I am using Entity Framework 6 as my ORM and I'm using code-first with an existing database. The database is SQL Server 2012 Standard.

In my database I have a view (dbo.vBoardReportLayouts) that functions as a joining table for a number of different elements. I've created an entity for this view and configured the navigation properties.

When I attempt to use this entity with LINQ entity framework generates a SQL query that tries to use a table that doesn't actually exist. Specifically it is looking for the `BoardReportLayoutPages` table.

---

### Now for all the gory details...

The vBoardReportLayouts view looks like this:

```
| ReportID | PageTypeId | PageId | LayoutID |
+----------+------------+--------+----------+
| 1        | 1          | 1      | 1        |
| 1        | 1          | 1      | 2        |
| 1        | 1          | 2      | 3        |
| 1        | 1          | 3      | 4        |
| 1        | 2          | 4      | 5        |
| 1        | 2          | 4      | 6        |
| 2        | 1          | 1      | 1        |
| 2        | 1          | 1      | 2        |
| 2        | 1          | 2      | 3        |
| 2        | 1          | 3      | 4        |
| 2        | 2          | 4      | 5        |
| 2        | 2          | 4      | 6        |
```

The BoardReportLayouts entity class:

```
[Table("vBoardReportLayouts")]
public partial class BoardReportLayout {
    public BoardReportLayout() {
        BoardReports = new HashSet<BoardReport>();
        PageTypes = new HashSet<PageType>();
        Pages = new HashSet<Page>();
        PageLayouts = new HashSet<PageLayout>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int BoardReportLayoutId { get; set; }

    public int BoardReportId { get; set; }

    public int PageTypeId { get; set; }

    public int PageId { get; set; }

    public int PageLayoutId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BoardReport> BoardReports { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PageType> PageTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Page> Pages { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PageLayout> PageLayouts { get; set; }
}
```

From the `OnModelCreating()` method of the dbContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BoardReportLayout>()
    .HasMany(e => e.BoardReports)
    .WithMany(e => e.BoardReportLayouts);

modelBuilder.Entity<BoardReportLayout>()
    .HasMany(e => e.PageTypes)
    .WithMany(e => e.BoardReportLayouts);

modelBuilder.Entity<BoardReportLayout>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Pages)
    .WithMany(e => e.BoardReportLayouts);

modelBuilder.Entity<BoardReportLayout>()
    .HasMany(e => e.PageLayouts)
    .WithMany(e => e.BoardReportLayouts);
```

The BoardReport, PageType, Page, and PageLayout entities all have the following property defined:

```
public virtual ICollection<BoardReportLayout> BoardReportLayouts { get; set; }
```

Executing this LINQ query:

```
var test = (from l in ppdb.BoardReportLayouts
            where l.BoardReportId == 8
            select l.Pages).SelectMany(p => p).ToList();
```

Generates this SQL:

```
SELECT [Join1].[PageId] AS [PageId], 
    [Join1].[PageTypeId] AS [PageTypeId], 
    [Join1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Join1].[ParameterValue] AS [ParameterValue], 
    [Join1].[SsrsPageParamterValue] AS [SsrsPageParamterValue], 
    [Join1].[TableOfContentsOrder] AS [TableOfContentsOrder]
    FROM  [dbo].[vBoardReportLayouts] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN  (
    SELECT [Extent2].[BoardReportLayout_BoardReportLayoutId] AS [BoardReportLayout_BoardReportLayoutId],
        [Extent3].[PageId] AS [PageId],
        [Extent3].[PageTypeId] AS [PageTypeId],
        [Extent3].[Name] AS [Name],
        [Extent3].[ParameterValue] AS [ParameterValue],
        [Extent3].[SsrsPageParamterValue] AS [SsrsPageParamterValue],
        [Extent3].[TableOfContentsOrder] AS [TableOfContentsOrder]
        FROM  [dbo].[BoardReportLayoutPages] AS [Extent2]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Pages] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent3].[PageId] = [Extent2].[Page_PageId]
    ) AS [Join1] ON [Extent1].[BoardReportLayoutId] = [Join1].[BoardReportLayout_BoardReportLayoutId]
    WHERE 8 = [Extent1].[BoardReportId]
```

The problem is in the `FROM` clause of the `[Join1]` table expression. I'm not sure why it is trying to use the table `dbo.BoardReportLayoutPages` since it could join directly from the view to the `Pages` table. The table `dbo.BoardReportLayoutPages` doesn't exist so this throws an exception.

Comment: Where does `[dbo].[vBoardReportLayouts]` come from? (Notice the v).

Comment: vBoardReportLayouts is a view I've created in the database. The rows in the Pages and PageLayouts tables are dated (start & end date) and the dates specify which BoardReports they apply to. A BoardReport is effectively a month but there are additional attributes stored for that month in the BoardReport table. I decided to use the view to handle the join logic for the tables so that I could still use native navigation properties in EF, but it looks like this isn't going to work out like I had hoped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit of code is specifying that the `BoardReportLayout` has a **many to many** relationship with pages:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BoardReportLayout>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Pages)
    .WithMany(e => e.BoardReportLayouts);
```

That means there should be a `BoardReportLayoutPages` table to model that relationship. The `BoardReportLayout` is supported by a view, so you had to write the sql to create it yourself, because code first would have generated tables to support the model you have defined here. If you do have a many-to-many relationship here, then you should have created the `BoardReportLayoutPages` as a table or view also.

But you also have a `PageId` property in the `BoardReportLayout`. This means that there is a second **one-to-many** relationship between a `Page` and `BoardReportLayout`s. If you want to get to a `BoardReportLayout`'s `Page` via this relationship then you should add a `public Page Page { get; set; }` navigation property.

Only you can decide whether you have two relationships here, or just one, and what type of relationship(s) you have.